# Iterative method of finding root

Tags: analytic-number-theory, na.numerical-analysis

I don't know much about numerical analysis. I need the following for help with my research in number theory.
Is there a simple(not multistep) iterative method of finding the root of a real-valued function f with the rate of convergence order bigger than or equal to 5?

Comment: I don't know of any such thing.  It would almost certainly be useless in practice since it would likely diverge unless you had a very good initial guess.  Meanwhile, finding a root of a real-valued function is so cheap computationally that there is no reason to look for such a high order of convergence.